# Generate a bar graph using ggplot2 and dplyr in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, dplyr

Need to plot a graph bar

Output error : Mapping should be created with `aes() or`aes_()`.

Code:

```r
cbPalette <- c("#CC79A7", "#D55E00", "#56B4E9", "#F0E442", "#009E73", "#0072B2", "#999999", "#E69F00")

mydata %>%
    group_by(workclass) %>%
    summarise(mean = mean(education.num, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    ggplot(new_data,aes(workclass, education.num, fill = workclass)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    labs(title = "Average Education Num vs workclass",
       x = "Workclass",
       y = "Average Education Num") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, angle = 90, hjust = 1))+
    scale_fill_manual(values = cbPalette[1]) +
    theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 10), 
        legend.title = element_text(size = 10)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(cbPalette))
```

Any suggestions

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: Try looking at your data after your call to `summarise`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several issues in your code.

1) When you use `summarise`, your column `education.num` will be replaced by `mean` in your dataset as you can see below:

```r
library(dplyr)

mydata %>%
  group_by(workclass) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(education.num, na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 9 x 2
  workclass         mean
  <chr>            <dbl>
1 ?                 9.26
2 Federal-gov      11.0 
3 Local-gov        11.0 
4 Never-worked      7.43
5 Private           9.88
6 Self-emp-inc     11.1 
7 Self-emp-not-inc 10.2 
8 State-gov        11.4 
9 Without-pay       9.07
```

2) then, in your `ggplot`, you are calling an another dataframe `new_data` and try to reuse `education.num` instead of `mean`. You can correct it by doing:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mydata %>%
  group_by(workclass) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(education.num, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(workclass, mean, fill = workclass)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(title = "Average Education Num vs workclass",
       x = "Workclass",
       y = "Average Education Num") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, angle = 90, hjust = 1),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 10), 
        legend.title = element_text(size = 10))
```

[image]

3) Finally, you are trying to replace filling values by `cbPalette`, however, you are providing only 8 values whereas you have 9 different classes, so you need to either add a new color and remove `?` like that:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mydata %>%
  group_by(workclass) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(education.num, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  filter(workclass != "?") %>%
  ggplot(aes(workclass, mean, fill = workclass)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(title = "Average Education Num vs workclass",
       x = "Workclass",
       y = "Average Education Num") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, angle = 90, hjust = 1),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 10), 
        legend.title = element_text(size = 10)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cbPalette)
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?